# Unpacking list_iterator from nltk.stanford.StanfordDependencyParser inside pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am trying to work with the StanfordDependencyParser inside of a pandas DataFrame.

```
from nltk.parse import stanford
import pandas as pd
dep_parser=stanford.StanfordDependencyParser()
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID' : [0,1,2], 'sentence' : ['This is the first s.', 'This is the 2nd s.', 'This isn''t the third s.']})
df['parsed'] = df.sentence.apply(dep_parser.raw_parse)
print(df)

   ID                sentence                                        parsed
0   0    This is the first s.  <list_iterator object at 0x000000000E849C18>
1   1      This is the 2nd s.  <list_iterator object at 0x000000000E8691D0>
2   2  This isnt the third s.  <list_iterator object at 0x000000000E8696A0>
```

But I'd like rather the text representation of the dependency graph inside of DataFrame column instead of the iterator, like so:

```
    ID                sentence                                        parsed
0   0    This is the first s.  [[(('s.', 'NN'), 'nsubj', ('This', 'DT')),(('s.', 'NN'), 'cop', ('is', 'VBZ')), (('s.', 'NN'), 'det', ('the', 'DT')),(('s.', 'NN'), 'amod', ('first', 'JJ'))]]
                   ...
```

I've tried to follow the the nltk documentation by working in steps in pandas, but it results in an attribute error:

```
 df['dep'] = [list(parse.triples()) for parse in df.parsed]
 AttributeError: 'list_iterator' object has no attribute 'triples'
```

Is there a way to unpack an iterator that appears as a value in a DataFrame? Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `list_iterator` is a mechanism for producing lists "on demand". It indeed does not have a method `triples()`, but the list that it produces in your case is indeed a list of triples:

```
df['dep'] = [list(parse) for parse in df['parsed']]
```

Comment: @f_lost The `parse` in your list comprehension is a local variable bound to the current individual list item. It is not a reference to the module `parse`. Your code is actually like this: `[list(X.triples()) for X in df.parsed]`. Clearly, `X` does not have `.triples()`.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response! The method `triples()` comes from the nltk.parse stanford module. The above dumps a one-item list containing a generator into each row of df.dep. I  can access those individually with, e.g.,  `g = df.iloc[0,1].pop(), ` and then can access g.nodes (not as good as triples(), but at least it's a start). But I can still can't vectorize the extraction over the entire df. `df.dep.apply(pop)` results in a NameError: 'pop' is not defined.

Comment: Why would `pop` be defined? Have you defined this function?

Comment: I thought that's what apply() did in pandas? `pop()` is defined for a list, and df.dep is a Series of lists, each containing one item. Shouldn't I be able to `pop()` each item from each list in the Series?

Comment: apply() cannot apply methods, it can apply only globally defined functions.

Comment: You can avoid loop through the dataframe twice, try: `df['parsed'] = df.sentence.apply(lambda x: list(dep_parser.raw_parse(x)))`

Comment: @alvas Thank you! lambda is the last piece I was missing. I can either use your statement as is and add use to `df.parsed.nodes` and `df.parsed.triples()` as needed, or create a new column entirely. Per my original intent to dump the triples representation into its own column, `df['parsed'] = df.sentence.apply(lambda x: [y for y in list(dep_parser.raw_parse(x))[0].triples()])` is sufficient.